# Adding list values to a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following object (view model) that I want to use:

```
public class assignmentViewModel 
{
    public string choreName { get; set; }
    public List<string> personName { get; set; }

}
```

LINQ statement:

```
            var avm = (from a in Assignments
                       join c in Chores on a.ChoreID equals c.ChoreId
                       join p in Persons on a.PersonID equals p.PersonID
                       select new assignmentViewModel
                       {
                           personName = p.PersonName.ToList(),
                           choreName = c.ChoreName
                       }).ToList();
```

I can have multiple people in an assignment.  I want to be able to pull back my data into this ViewModel.  The error I'm getting currently is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<char>`'
>   to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`'

My data (if it helps) is:

```
chore #1
person 1

chore #2
person 1 
person 2
```

The Person model is:

```
public partial class person
{
    public int personID { get; set; }
    public string personName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime personDOB { get; set; }
    public string personEmail { get; set; }
    public string personPhone { get; set; }
    public string personPhoneCarrier { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'` which part you don't understand?

Comment: Is PersonName `IEnumerable<char>`? Show us the `Person` model

Comment: @LewsTherin In all likelihood, `PersonName` is a `string`, which would make it an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: @JLRishe - you are correct about that.  I'm having a hard time thinking about how to change it to fix it.

Comment: OK so I think the query to find the people for an assignment should be done inside the object initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for *Grouping* here, you need to group the records based on `choreName`, I would do it like this:

```
(from a in Assignments
 join c in Chores on a.ChoreID equals c.ChoreId
 join p in Persons on a.PersonID equals p.PersonID
 select new 
        {
            person = p,
            choreName = c.ChoreName
        })
  .GroupBy(x => x.choreName)
  .Select(g => new assignmentViewModel
               {
                   personName = g.Select(x => x.person.PersonName).ToList()
                   choreName =  g.Key
               }).ToList();
```